# calling iis express from another PC

Tags: iis, signalr, iis-express

I am going a bit round in circles here.

I have a MVC ASP.NET app.  It also uses SignalR.

My PC is Windows 8.1
It uses IIS8 Client.
Because of this IIS Client I have been told I can only have 1 current signalR connection.

I raised this issue with the SignalR chaps on their forum.

They told me to download and use IIS express.

So, I uninstalled IIS8 and installed IIS8 Express.

I launched my app via a DOS window using:

"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\inetpub\wwwroot /port:1234

I then open a browser and type in:

**http://localhost:1234/**

And my web app starts.

However, if I replace the localhost with '127.0.0.1' or/and the DHCP IP address I get:

**Bad Request - Invalid Hostname.**

Now, I want to be able to access this web site from within my network using the DHCP IP address but it looks lie I cannot.

Is my conclusion(s) correct?

What are my options?

Is there a way to get IIS Client to support many Signalr connections?
Is there a way to configure IIS so that I can use the DHCP?
Is there an alternative to using IIS?
Is there an alternative to using SignalR so that IIS Client can support concurrent SignalR connections?

Thanks

Comment: You need to update iisexpress bindings - take a look at this post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I have seen that link already and followed it to the letter but i must be too stupid as it did not work for me :(